# Java - Hibernate envers not working in Jar

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, executable-jar

We use Hibernate Envers for keeping object change history. It's been working fine in development, now that we've build a JAR out of the code it does not work anymore. We've tried numerous things, like upgrading, checking if the database connection is right etc. Everything works fine when running in Intellij itself, just not when running the compiled JAR.

We get the issue when initialising the Hibernate session factory, we've not done any transactions when getting this error. A lot of answers online have a solution for the context wherein a session is not accessed correctly, this is not the case here.

The `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.41'
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

group = 'com.obscured'
version = '1.0'
description = "Obscured API"

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.10'
    implementation group: 'com.sparkjava', name: 'spark-core', version: '2.9.3'
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.5'
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.5'
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20170516'
    implementation group: 'de.mkammerer', name: 'argon2-jvm', version: '2.2'
    implementation group: 'com.maxmind.geoip2', name: 'geoip2', version: '2.9.0'
    implementation group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4'
    implementation group: 'com.stripe', name: 'stripe-java', version: '16.1.0'
    implementation group: 'com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer', name: 'owasp-java-html-sanitizer', version: '20191001.1'
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.geocoder-java', name: 'geocoder-java', version: '0.16'
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.18'
    implementation group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core', version: '5.1.4'

    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.4.30.Final'
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.4.30.Final'
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-c3p0', version: '5.4.30.Final'
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-ehcache', version: '5.4.30.Final'
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-envers', version: '5.4.30.Final'
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate.search', name: 'hibernate-search-mapper-orm', version: '6.0.1.Final'
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate.search', name: 'hibernate-search-backend-lucene', version: '6.0.1.Final'

    implementation group: 'com.google.firebase', name: 'firebase-admin', version: '7.0.0'

    implementation group: 'com.github.hotchemi', name: 'khronos', version: '0.9.0'
    implementation group: 'org.everit.json', name: 'org.everit.json.schema', version: '1.5.1'
    implementation group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.11.3'
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.688'
    implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.12.2'
    implementation 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.10.3'

    implementation group: 'org.reflections', name: 'reflections', version: '0.9.12'
    implementation group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.1.1'

    // Swagger
    implementation group: 'io.swagger.core.v3', name: 'swagger-core', version: '2.1.6'
    implementation group: 'io.swagger.core.v3', name: 'swagger-jaxrs2', version: '2.1.6'
    implementation group: 'io.swagger.core.v3', name: 'swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer', version: '2.1.6'
    implementation group: 'io.swagger.core.v3', name: 'swagger-annotations', version: '2.1.4'

    implementation 'io.github.cdimascio:java-dotenv:3.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    zip64 = true
    archiveName = 'obscured.jar'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.obscured.Obscured'
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    with jar
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin/'
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin/'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

The command we run (in the main directory, just to be safe):

```
java -jar obscured.jar
```

The code being executed where the error occurs:

```
try {
    val cfg = Configuration()
    cfg.configure("db/hibernate.cfg.xml")
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://" + this.host + ":" + this.port?.toString() + "/" + this.database + "?autoReconnect=true")
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", this.username)
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", this.password)
    factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory()
} catch (ex: Throwable) {
    System.err.println("Failed user create sessionFactory object.$ex")
    throw ExceptionInInitializerError(ex)
}
```

The error we're getting:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversService]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.TypeContributorImpl.contribute(TypeContributorImpl.java:22)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:391)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:132)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
        at com.obscured.database.Connection.configureHibernate(Connection.kt:69)
        ... 2 more
```

Again, this just seems to be happening once it is in a JAR, all dependencies are available and doing just fine. We've tried using several different versions of Hibernate dependencies, however this seems to be an issue for us across the board.

We even decompiled the JAR to see if the same files are there as they are in our IDE, and they are, so no luck there. We've obviously search the internet for answers with no positive result.

Comment: I would suggest to use one of the available gradle plugins to create the fat jar, or even better - spring boot.

Comment: shadowJar did the job for us eventually, thank you!

Comment: For anybody finding this. Eventually we even skipped shadowJar entirely and are now using jib.